# Why can't Thor pick up his hammer?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

In The Avengers after falling from great height and blasting through the cage, Thor seems to have lost his control over the hammer, why did this happen?

Comment: How did you conclude that he lost control over the Hammer? Just because he is not holding it?

Comment: I don't really think there is a a specific answer. It's just to get you thinking. Is that he couldn't lift the hammer, or that he wouldn't? Was he scared, because he knew he might need to kill his brother? Who knows? I saw the second movie today, and there was no answer, although someone else picks it up...

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/was-thor-unworthy-during-the-avengers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it is not that he *cannot* do it, but that he is emotionally very much shaken and disappointed, since this is right after Loki tried to kill him (which is what that fall was supposed to do). What we see in that scene is hesitation, not failure.

In the next Thor scene, we see him lift it. He either can do so or cannot. There is no "he can lift it, but not summon it" for Mjölnir. And, obviously, he *can* lift it.

Comment: Note that Thor could not lift Mjolnir for the better part of the Thor movie (it's pretty much the centre of the plot). His ability to do so is not a given. But you are correct that the scene in question is not a matter of inability.

Answer (score 1):

Thor can pick up his hammer he is just taking his time...  at about 1 hour and 37 minutes the scenes catch up and come back to thor as everyone is "suiting up" and you see him pick the hammer up hold it in the air and lightning comes down and his armor seems to come down with the lightning.  Here is a video of the scene:

This may have been confusing at first because Marvel split the scene up into a couple parts over a few minutes.

Also while I can't prove it I believe he could have summoned the hammer do his hand and just didn't want to or the directors decided that the scene had more of a more decisive and determined feel the way they did it.  I believe this possible because the Marvel Cinematic Universe and the comics don't always agree.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, because he wasn't going to go back. In that act he became unworthy. Then he decides he's definitely going back to fight, so he's again worthy and he can summon the lightning, his armor.

Answer (score -4):

Thor, being the God of Thunder, can summon his hammer as well as being the only guy to lift his hammer. The reason he cannot summon it after crashing on the field is because it needs to be energized by thunder to to do his bidding, without which it's just a heavy hammer. Only an electric force field around the hammer allows it to hover to him. That's why you see him walking towards the hammer, lifting it and energizing it by causing a thunderstorm to strike him and his hammer.

Comment: Is there some evidence to back up you claim?

Comment: I read about him energizing his hammer by summoning thunder in a comic book, long ago, and in the same. He fails to unleash a thunder at the enemy and looses his grip on it and is unable to summon it. But later in the same comic, he  finds the strength to energizing it, he regains his grip on it and issues a thunderbolt towards an army of aliens.

Comment: Surely now you can "UpVote" this thread !

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/Mjolnir doesn't state any such limitation.

Comment: @SandySands: That's not evidence. That's a wild claim with no proof.

Comment: "Wielding Mjölnir, Thor can summon and control the powers of the storm, causing rain, wind, thunder and lightning." ([Source](http://marvel.com/universe/Thor_complete_powers)) I'd call Marvel's site ("real site"; not "just" a wiki!) the official source for this version of Thor, and it's quite clear from this quote that Thor uses Mjölnir to control the thunder, and not nice versa.